# LSI IT vs IT_ACM firmware

Tags: raid, lsi, firmware

I purchased an older LSI 9300-4i card and before I put it into production I want to flash the latest firmware.  In addition to IT vs IR flavours of available firmware, there's also an IT vs IT_ACM flavour.

What is the ACM suffix for?

I will be connecting only a single drive (no raid) to this card, for hot-swapping a drive tray.  So I don't wait raid, which is why I thought I would just flash the IT firmware.  But IT_ACM has me scratching my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context ACM stands for "Active Cable Management". "_ACM" firmware images are to be flashed onto adapters with external ports to enable optional "ACM Support" feature. You do not need it for your all internal card.